# Python 3.3 blueprints

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I am interested in knowing which language changes are going to happen in Python 3.3 (without having to subscribe to the [developer mailing list](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev) and monitor the flow of messages).

I found [this page](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html) on python.org, but I wonder if there is any additional reference that fellow programmers would recommend.

Comment: With a reputation of 4670 I don't believe in statements like "googling skills could not find it".

Comment: Even if he could google it easily, it's still a valid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PEP 398](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0398/) lists some features that might be included in 3.3:

> Candidate PEPs:
>
> ```
> PEP 362: Function Signature Object
> PEP 380: Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator
> PEP 382: Namespace Packages
> PEP 393: Flexible String Representation
> PEP 395: Module Aliasing
> PEP 397: Python launcher for Windows
> PEP 3143: Standard daemon process library
> PEP 3151: Reworking the OS and IO exception hierarchy
> ```
>
> (Note that these are not accepted yet and even if they are, they might
>   not be finished in time for Python 3.3.)
>
> Other planned large-scale changes:
>
> ```
> Addition of the "packaging" module, replacing "distutils"
> Implementing __import__ using importlib
> Email version 6
> A standard event-loop interface (PEP by Jim Fulton pending)
> Adding the faulthandler module.
> Breaking out standard library and docs in separate repos?
> A PEP on supplementing C modules with equivalent Python modules?
> ```

Answer (score 6):

[PEP 398](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0398/) lists PEPs that might make it into Python 3.3.

> This document describes the development and release schedule for
>   Python 3.3. The schedule primarily concerns itself with PEP-sized
>   items. Small features may be added up to and including the first beta
>   release. Bugs may be fixed until the final release, which is planned
>   for August 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I've recorded a 7 min screencast [What's New in Python 3.3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYXnQzKcsQ0). It's based on the What's New document from the Python documentation.

**Edit:** Althought the main focus of the screencast is Python 3.3, it contains elements of PyCharm IDE promotion.

Comment: People should be advised that **the linked video is clearly aimed to promote PyCharm** (the python editor by JetBrains). That said, the video *does* showcase some of the new features of python 3.3 in a concise and effective way. +1 for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look through the blog posts syndicated on http://planet.python.org/

There are a number of interesting posts on in-development items for 3.3 like Email 6, import, and others, if you're interested in the "how" and "why" rather than just the "what".

Comment: That's a lot of blog posts to wade through, for someone who's not willing to subscribe the main development mailing list.